# CubeMX STM32 HAL + FreeRTOS

Tags: eclipse, stm32, freertos, hal

I've would like to check whether STM32 Workbench works properly or not.

So, I've created new project for my F7 Discovery. I am using the HAL library and also enabled FreeRTOS. As FreeRTOS needs an independent timer, I enabled TIM1 for HAL and SysTick works for FreeRTOS.

Unfortunately, while debugging the project in Workbench, the program each time ends in the TIM1 interrupt routine, again and again, but I did NOT set any breakpoints here. How can I debug my code if everything I can see during debugging is TIM1 [ISR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler)?

Comment: Add your TIM1 configuration code.

Comment: TIM1 configuration is as in the https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak8yaxR1DeFsnXlNb1Wfz8eJKcG4, this is created by CubeMX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it this is a feature of the **r0p1 M7 core**. ST only licensed the r0p1 core. Unsure if newer versions or model of the chip will be any better.

I read on another forum that this could perhaps mitigate the problem:

```
  (DBGMCU)->APB1FZ = 0x7E01BFF;
  (DBGMCU)->APB2FZ = 0x70003;
```

Comment: Hey! Shall I add these lines to my code or maybe they are a part of FreeRTOS port?

Comment: Well yes, you need to find the address for these hardware registers and set them in the initial part of your software (or with gdb when debugging). In HAL library there seem to be some functions for setting them (DBGMCU_APB1PeriphConfig() and DBGMCU_APB2PeriphConfig())

Comment: I have the same problem again but now regarding USB. Where can I find description of these registers?

Comment: try and search for this document: DM00124865 (section 40.16.5)